# CUDA-capability and CUDA version: compatible?

Tags: cuda, compute-capability

I have one machine with a 1.1 compute-capability CUDA GPU. I want to reinstall CUDA and I think I'll go with 5.0;

Is there any such thing as compatibility between CUDA-capability and CUDA's version? Will I get troubles in using CUDA 5.0 with a C-C 1.1. GPU?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the time of writing, all CUDA versions were backwards compatible with older CUDA compatible hardware.

So the CUDA toolkit through to version 6.5 will work perfectly with a compute 1.1 capability device, although a number features present in the toolkit are not supported on these older devices. However there has been a progressive deprecation of older hardware in newer tool kits since then. As of June 2019:

- Support for compute 1.x capability devices was removed in CUDA 7.
- Support for compute 2.x capability devices was removed in CUDA 9.