# Can Geforce 9500 GT run CUDA Toolkit 5.0?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Can Geforce 9500 GT run CUDA Toolkit 5.0?

In the homepage: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Geforce 9500 GT have Compute Capability 1.0 this means only run CUDA 1.0?

Comment: According to Release notes of Cuda Toolkit (5): http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html, section "Supported NVIDIA Hardware", all GPUs listed in https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus are supported. So, you can use newer version of Toolkit. But with older GPU you are limited in what you can run on GPU (some features are disabled). Here is the table for Compute capabilities: http://www.geeks3d.com/20100606/gpu-computing-nvidia-cuda-compute-capability-comparative-table/

Comment: @osgx this seems fine to me as an answer.  Would you mind posting it as an answer?  user916933: cuda toolkit release versions and cuda compute capability are two completely separate ideas, as indicated by osgx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CUDA-capability and CUDA version: compatible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600468/cuda-capability-and-cuda-version-compatible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of 2013, CUDA Toolkit supports all CUDA devices, even with Compute Capability 1.0 (abbreviated as CC 1.0). And CC 1.0 devices are supported in all versions of Toolkit. Answer is "Yes, Geforce 9500 GT can be used with CUDA Toolkit 5.0".

According to Release notes of current Cuda Toolkit (version 5), http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html, section "Supported NVIDIA Hardware":

> Supported NVIDIA Hardware
>
> See http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_gpus.html.

So, all GPUs listed in http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus are supported, from GeForce 8xxx with CC 1.0  up to most modern Tesla K20 with CC 3.5.

You always can use newest version of Toolkit to work with any generation of CUDA-enabled devices. With older GPU you are limited in what you can run on GPU (some features are added in newer CC). Some features, like 64-bit floating point (double) or performance counters are unavailable in CC 1.0.

Here are some tables for features in different Compute capabilities:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications

or

http://www.geeks3d.com/20100606/gpu-computing-nvidia-cuda-compute-capability-comparative-table/

As I know, Toolkit usually emits several variants of code, for every supported CC. At runtime compatible variant will be loaded by CUDA Driver.

Comment: I appreciate the answers. I apologize if I made a duplicate question. I'm trying now starting with CUDA

Comment: There are wonderful books and online courses for CUDA, e.g. in coursera ([Heterogeneous programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/hetero)). Can you press the "v" symbol right to the answer if your problem is solved?